# CSS border circle animation is not working for rectangles

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create a border animation for a rectangle. unfortunately the circle effect is very buggy. I Animation should include a border with a fade cicle around a rectangle.

I have heard that I should to try it with SVG but i have no idea how SVG animations are working and did not found something similar to my usecase online.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  justify-content: center
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: conic-gradient(#4429F2 20deg, transparent 120deg);
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  width: 395px;
  height: 195px;
  background: #E5E7EB;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a better-looking result by making the rotating part into a circle which has a radius the maximum of the width and height of the element.

However, whether this is enough depends on exactly what you require in terms of the speed of travel.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff0;
  rbackground-color: pink;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  roverflow: visible;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  justify-content: center
}

.container::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  background-image: conic-gradient(#4429F2 20deg, transparent 120deg);
  width: 150%;
  /*height: 150%;*/
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  width: 395px;
  height: 195px;
  background: #E5E7EB;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: How can i avoid that the animation is going slower in the middle of the top and bottom?